# How did the Daleks regain their numbers?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

Since the end of the Time War the Daleks have been near extinct and some of the plots of the previously released seasons have been about the Daleks regaining their former strength (Bad Wolf Station, The Cult of Scaro's Genesis Ark and experiments in New York, the Daleks Paradigm). the only time that we see they suddenly appeared with their former numbers was when  Daleks Thane of the Cult of Scaro broke the Time Lock during an emergency Temporal Shift and inadvertently saved Davros's ship.

Yet after The Doctor caused a second Big Band with the Pandorica the Daleks seem to be a full blown empire as we see when they capture him, Amy and Rory to deal with the Daleks Asylum.

I am wondering, is it explained how the Daleks regained their numbers, or did The Doctor inadvertently bring them back to full strength with the Pandorica?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the "new Paradigm" of Daleks got away at the end of "Victory of the Daleks" they presumably just started cloning themselves to make more, since that's how Daleks make new Daleks and by the next time we see them, their race has been restored.

Answer (score 0):

Either by travelling through time, experimenting on other species, or both. Daleks are shown to be extremely cunning and resourceful, so it's no surprise they would regain their numbers by the hundreds or even thousands.

Answer (score 0):

Simply stated, since The Daleks have access to time travel, they functionally have infinite time to regain their numbers. They can Emergency Temporal Shift off somewhere, set themselves up in a remote base, and spend a few hundred years rebuilding their armies.  Heck, they even rebuilt Skaro completely at some point.

There are certainly multiple Dalek campaigns going on in various parts of the universe at any one time, either an active attack, or a strategic sequester to recover from one of said active battles.