# Where did the Daleks in "Into the Dalek" (#243) come from?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

In episode **#243 - "Into the Dalek"**, there is at least one large ship full of Daleks, and a rebel ship of humans that are fighting them.

Are these Daleks new creations of the multicoloured Daleks from the **#205 - "Victory of the Daleks"** episode, as discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66497/how-did-the-daleks-regain-their-numbers)

Or, are they anything to do with the events of **#240 - "Day of the Doctor"**, now that we know the Daleks are not destroyed.

I was surprised when it wasn't addressed in the episode and I am unable to find any other people asking the question on the nets.

Comment: It's really been annoying me that thousands of Daleks just keep on showing up. On the other hand, it _could_ be argued that this is a rare instance of the show getting time travel right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In "Asylum of the Daleks", we see that the Daleks have fully restored their race(presumably through cloning, as is their standard procedure). In that episode, they are shown to have at least several battleships' worth of numbers. I don't see any reason to assume that the Daleks that appear in "Into the Dalek" are not simply a part of that group, as we are given no reason to think otherwise. The Daleks are back as a functioning force, and it was the entire point of Series 5's "Victory of the Daleks" to make them such.

Answer (score 6):

#### The Daleks in 'Into The Dalek' are likely some of the many more survivors of the Time War after the tampering the three Doctors did in the 'Day of the Doctor' episode.

Time has been rewritten with the Doctor(s) returning to the past and editing the events of the Time War in the 'Day of the Doctor' episode. It may have been the confluence of the three Doctors (and their other counterparts) which may have allowed them to alter the fixed point in time, changing the outcome of the Time War.

- However, the change of this supposed fixed point means the Daleks may not have been victims of genocide or trapped along with the Time Lords. This may mean at least some survived past that point in time. Daleks had escaped in the previous iteration of the Time War, just far fewer and those were hunted down, whenever possible, by the Doctor.
- In theory, this may mean Daleks from the Time War are still out there. I suspect some of these may be the Daleks we see in the Parliament of the Daleks. (TV: Asylum of the Daleks). They are the classic bronze/gold we expect when we see functioning Daleks.

[image]

Does this mean the existence of the colorful New Paradigm "iDaleks" have ceased to exist? Not at all. The genesis of the New Paradigm Daleks was due to the escape of three damaged Daleks to 1941 Earth. They are also of the Classic Dalek coloration and configuration.

[image]

- These three Daleks carried a Progenitor Device with pure Dalek DNA. This events which was seen in 'Victory of the Daleks' could continue to occur in the mainstream universe, since it would be possible for the three Daleks to honestly believe they were the last Daleks in the galaxy.

[image]

This event does not invalidate any other Dalek event, leaving the New Paradigm Daleks in play and with the ability to create more Daleks like themselves if they wished (a terrifying thought).

Comment: I want to point out as well that at least some of the iDaleks (GREAT name by the way) have joined up with the original Daleks; in *Asylum of the Daleks* we see a white Dalek next to the Emperor. It's possible that these new Daleks have been given special roles (like command, or science, or something) and the regular gold Daleks are the grunts

Comment: @Jason "the regular gold Daleks are the grunts" - +1! Nice image.

Comment: I don't think that TDOTD actually changed anything, though. It just changed what we knew. For one thing, the conclusion of the Time War was never said to be a fixed point (such a concept would likely be meaningless in a war as unconcerned with the stability of time anyway); the Doctor just couldn't change it because nothing was supposed to be able to bypass the time lock. The War always ended with Gallifrey being saved, I think, because it is a part of a larger loop (the Trenzalore conflict, which needs Gallifrey to be saved in order to happen, but also causes the salvation of Gallifrey).

Answer (score 0):

Both of the other answers are fine but it needs to be said that the events from the Doctor's past which are represented in the episodes are not set in stone. In his universe time is constantly in flux. His interactions with it are sometimes made as to have not happened due to these changes. They had a long lesson on this wibbly wobbly timey wimey stuff during several episodes revolving around what is and isn't a fixed point.

> Fixed points in time were moments in the space-time continuum at which events were set in stone and could never, ever be changed, no matter what. The Time Lords knew which points in time were "fixed", which the Ninth Doctor said was a maddening experience to have to go through. (TV: The Parting of the Ways) This was called "the burden of the Time Lords" by the Tenth Doctor, who was trying to explain to Donna why he couldn't prevent Mount Vesuvius from erupting or save the people of Pompeii. (TV: The Fires of Pompeii)

-[tardis wika](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Fixed_point_in_time)